Node addon module with cuda code gives runtime link error (using docker container)
I am trying to write a node-addon-api module with cuda code.
I am using a docker container:
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.5.0-devel-ubuntu22.04
first compiled the cuda files to make a static library:
nvcc  --compiler-options '-fPIC'  -rdc=true -c -o temp.o cuda_lib.cu
nvcc --compiler-options '-fPIC'  -dlink -o gpuCode.o temp.o -lcudart
ar cru libgpu.lib gpuCode.o temp.o
ranlib libgpu.lib

Then tried to link it with the rest of the module in my binding.gyp:
 {
  "targets": [
    {
    "target_name": "addon",
    "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
    "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
    "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
    "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
      "sources": ["addon.cc", "myobject.cc"],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")",
      ],
    "libraries": [
          "/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart_static.a",
          "/usr/src/app/libgpu.lib",
    ],
      'defines': [ 'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ],
      "cflags": [
        "-std=c++11"
      ],
    }
  ]

}

Everything compiles and runs without problem on my local windows machine. Docker version however gives this error when running:
node: symbol lookup error: /usr/src/app/build/Release/addon.node: undefined symbol: __cudaRegisterFatBinary
I am very confused what is the reason, as cudart is linked from what I understand.
nm ./build/Release/addon.node
I can see __cudaRegisterFatBinary is defined in my .node file.
I searched a lot, tried different solutions, nothing works :(

just for reference, it turned out that the linking order was wrong! so crazy that windows doesn't care but linux does!
this fixes my issue:
"libraries": [
          "/usr/src/app/libgpu.lib",
          "/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart_static.a",
    ],

